# c++ reference parameter not updated

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple function to extract the next number from an expression in a string and my problem is that the reference parameter ioIsValidExpression is not being updated after the function exits. It looks like I am actually referencing the correct variable (and not a temporary) since the addresses of test3 (as it is called before calling getNextNumber(...)) and ioIsValidExpression (its name when inside the function) are the same.

I expect this to be an embarassing mistake somewhere but I'm getting nowhere trying to figure this one out; I've included my int main and int getNextNumber with a comment line where I return a value from the function.

```
int getNextNumber(std::string& iExpression, int& ioLoopShift, bool& ioIsValidExpression)
{
    //spaces are ignored, a minus is a unary minus (so must be seated next to a number (no spaces between '-' and number))
    int length = iExpression.size(); //evaluate only once
    bool unaryMinusFound = false;
    bool numberFound = false;

    int oSubExpression = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if((int)iExpression[i] == 32)
        {
            if(!numberFound)
            {
                if(!unaryMinusFound)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    ioIsValidExpression = false;
                    td::cout << "address of ioIsValidExpression: " << &ioIsValidExpression << ", value: " << ioIsValidExpression << "\n";
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return unaryMinusFound? -1 * oSubExpression: oSubExpression;
            }
        }
        if((int)iExpression[i] == 45 && !unaryMinusFound)
        {
            unaryMinusFound = true;
            continue;
        }
        if((int)iExpression[i] >= 48 && (int)iExpression[i] <= 57)
        {
            numberFound = true;
            oSubExpression = (int)(iExpression[i]-48) + 10*oSubExpression;
            ioLoopShift++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //garbage characters
            ioIsValidExpression = false;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return unaryMinusFound? -1 * oSubExpression: oSubExpression;
}
```

int main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string test = " - 45 & ";
    int test2 = 0;
    bool test3 = true;
    std::cout << getNextNumber(test,test2,test3) << ", address of test3: " << &test3 << ", value: " << test3 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output from running the program:

```
address of ioIsValidExpression: 0xbf86e58f, value: 0
0, address of test3: 0xbf86e58f, value: 1
```

Comment: It's unspecified what order the outputs are evaluated in. Your `bool` is being evaluated to `true` before the function changes it to `false`. Also, prefer `'0'` to 48, as it isn't always 48.

Comment: Consider the case of stream manipulators with `std::cout` ... you can't have the manipulator being evaluated on `std::cout` before other elements in the sequence of `operator>>` calls ... that would completely mess up the output.

Comment: @Jason, It still does the output in order, but the arguments can be evaluated in whatever order it pleases. It uses the result of one `operator<<` as an argument to another. The innermost call is outputted first, but by that time, the outermost argument could have been evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which function arguments (and your output statement is a chain of functions) are evaluated is unspecified. Consider how it works correctly upon holding the result of the function in a variable before outputting the whole thing: [test](http://liveworkspace.org/code/90bd701efffce38d3244ac5fc873afde)

```
int temp = getNextNumber(test, test2, test3);
std::cout << temp << ", address of test3: " << &test3 << ", value: " << test3 << "\n";
```

Output:

> address of ioIsValidExpression: 0xbfaa85cf, value: 0
>   0, address of test3: 0xbfaa85cf, value: 0

Comment: Doesn't cdecl calling convention create some type of ordering? For the overloaded  `operator>>` there are two arguments.  There is no sequence point for the ordering of the evaluation of those two arguments, but it does mean that either the first argument is initially evaluated, modifying `test3` before it can be evaluated, or `test3` is evaluate first, and then the nested function calls that comprise the first argument to the outer-most function call are not reflected in that evaluation.  I think that can be the only ambiguous ordering.

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes sense now it has been pointed out to me...this one was driving me crazy and is not a mistake I want to make again!

Comment: It only defines the ordering of the parameters on the stack. The compiler is still free to compute their values in any order, as long as it pushes them in that order. Plus, the Standard does not deal in calling conventions in this manner.